# How do I load data into a Crystal Report with Sub Reports in ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

This loads data into the report (though I'm still getting errors because I think I'm missing the sub-report):

```
var finalSchedulesTable = Session["finalSchedulesTable"] as DataTable;

var rpDoc = new TVDataSchedule();

rpDoc.SetDataSource(finalSchedulesTable);

crvSchedules.ReportSource = rpDoc;

crvSchedules.DataBind();

Session["Report"] = rpDoc;
```

Here's the report:

[image]

And here's the subReport if you double click on "subShows" on the main report:

[image]

The error I'm getting is this:

This field name is not known. Details: errorKind Error in File temp_b2eab357-8e61-4168-9725-7b3a9ca7388d {D18CEA07-F52D-42D8-BF5A-2165A733165D}.rpt: Error in formula frmSourceLeft1: 'Dim tmpTitle ' This field name is not known. Details: errorKind

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
var rpDoc = new TVDataSchedule();

rpDoc.SetDataSource(finalSchedulesTable);

ReportDocument subShows = rpDoc.Subreports["subShows"];
subShows.SetDataSource(finalShowsTable);

crvSchedules.ReportSource = rpDoc;

crvSchedules.DataBind();
```